# Angular 8: access the assets folder when running ng build --prod --base-href './project1'

Tags: angular, sass

My client want me to deploy multiple projects on the same `ngnix` server with the following configuration.

```
location /project1/ {
    alias /usr/local/var/www/project1/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /project1/index.html;
}
```

In the above configuration I could not access the assets folder as it's in the project1 folder and I try to access it from the root of the domain example src:

`url('/assets/fonts/texta/Texta-Regular/Texta-Regular.eot')`

When I change the path with src: `url('./assets/fonts/texta/Texta-Regular/Texta-Regular.eot')` I'm getting following problem when building the production build

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): ModuleError:
>   Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
>   /Users/Desktop/personal/projects/example/src/styles.scss:10115:13:
>   Can't resolve
>   './assets/fonts/texta/Texta-Regular/Texta-Regular.eot%3F' in
>   '/Users/Desktop/personal/projects/example/src'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use absolute paths starting from "/" so you have 2 options:

1- Using relative paths (with "../" to go back up the hierarchy). This one is a bit messy but easy to do.

2- Define your assets folder in the compilerOptions of your tsconfig.json as follows:

```
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"],
}
}
```

Then you can use "@assets/" in your Url. Take note of the baseUrl and assets url and change it accordingly based on your project structure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have not problem to compile url('./assets/fonts/texta/Texta-Regular/Texta-Regular.eot').
Please check the Texta-Regular.eot presence.

Answer (score 0):

rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls flag in the angular.json did worked for me.